# C# class constructor precondition

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container

Lets say I have a class, with a constructor

```
public RepresentativeService(IUserContext userContext, INavServiceClient navServiceClient)
{
    _userContext = userContext;
    _navServiceClient = navServiceClient;
}
```

I would want to add preconditions

```
if (userContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userContext));
if (navServiceClient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navServiceClient));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userContext.CustomerNumber)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userContext.CustomerNumber));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userContext.PersonalCode)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userContext.PersonalCode));
```

to ensure that service method would work correctly. Furthermore it makes no sense to add conditions to methods, for example

```
public void Appoint(PrivatePerson person)
```

should not check if userContext is null or some value that it needs is String.Empty. It might be poor decision to add preconditions to constructor but on the other hand it would fail fast and give correct precise error.

Service is just a facade for webservice, that comes from 3-rd party. Without preconditions I enable user to say something like : "remove representative with null id", that does not seem correct. If I do not add them it does not make sense to add unit/integration tests for them as well.

My question is : should I add preconditions and where?

Comment: Adding preconditions in the constructor is generally a good idea. You are protecting your invariants. You do not want someone to instantiate your class with bad state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding preconditions in the constructor is generally a good idea. You are protecting your invariants. You do not want someone to instantiate your class with bad state. For example something being null when it cannot be null. You should also add preconditions to methods that make sense in the context of the method. In your example, check if person is null.

```
public void Appoint(PrivatePerson person)
{
   if (person == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));
   }

   // code
}
```

This is also called Defensive Programming. You assume callers of your code are passing you unusual parameters so you check for invalid parameters inside your code. It's very good practice.

In regards to testing, you should test your preconditions in unit tests. Your preconditions are part of your code execution flow. If you don't exercise them in tests you can't be sure they are working as you expect.

In summary, add preconditions everywhere you want to guarantee correct object state which is usually everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Adding precondition in constructors are actually pretty common. Heck, it's even used by CLR classes that we use and love! 
Fore example, if you decompile `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable` you will find this constructor:

```
internal OrderedEnumerable(IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  if (keySelector == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
  this.source = source;
  this.parent = (OrderedEnumerable<TElement>) null;
  this.keySelector = keySelector;
  this.comparer = comparer != null ? comparer : (IComparer<TKey>) Comparer<TKey>.Default;
  this.descending = descending;
}
```